# Is it possible to solve for a symbol with units in python?

Tags: python, sympy, solver, units-of-measurement

I'd like to solve an equation with a solver but the equation has numbers with units. I've tried using pint for units and sympy for the solver

```
import sympy as sy
import pint
import scipy.constants as cnst

u = pint.UnitRegistry()
Q = u.Quantity

k=cnst.k*u.joule/u.K
T=1100*u.K

x = sy.Symbol('x')

D0 = 0.214*u.cm**2/u.sec
D1=D0*(sy.exp((-3.65*u.eV)/(k*T)))
print(sy.erf(((40e-9*u.m).to('cm')/(2*(D1*60*u.sec)**(1/2))).magnitude))
answer = sy.solve(1-sy.erf(((40e-9*u.m).to('cm')/(2*(D1*x*u.sec)**(1/2))).magnitude - 0.00001),x)
print(answer)
```

nothing gets returned though. Any idea what I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Try using sympy units

```
>>> from sympy import units
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> solve(3*units.feet-x*2,x)
[3*foot/2]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Smichr's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58897154/12267732) works fine if you can define the equations programmatically. In cases where the equations are defined as strings (for example when reading them from a file), this solution might help:

```py
"""
Note: the most recent version of pint contains a bug 
(https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/pull/1701). Install this version of pint to 
run below code: https://github.com/BenPortner/pint/tree/fix-subtraction-error.
"""

from pint.facets.plain.registry import build_eval_tree, tokenizer
from pint.util import string_preprocessor
from pint import UnitRegistry
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import Symbol, solve

# define system of equations (Note: 0 = 1 m - A instead of A = 1 m)
equations = [
    "1 m - A",
    "A + 200 mm - B",
    "B * kg/m - C",
    "A * B * C - D"
]

# define unknowns
unknowns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

# parse equations
# note: parsing first with pint to convert 200 mm -> 200 * mm etc.
parsed = [
  parse_expr(build_eval_tree(tokenizer(string_preprocessor(eq))).to_string())
  for eq in equations
]

# solve equation system
solution = solve(parsed, [Symbol(s) for s in unknowns])

# parse units in solution
ureg = UnitRegistry()
solution = [ureg(str(r)).to_base_units() for r in solution[0]]

# for reference
expected = [
    ureg("1 m"),  # A
    ureg("1.2 m"),  # B
    ureg("1.2 kg"),  # C
    ureg("1.44 kg * m^2"),  # D
]
```